# MapPartitions does not execute print

Tags: pyspark

I've a problem that I'm hoping someone can explain it to me.

Let's assume my data looks like this:

```
  ('1', ['1', '1', '-1']),
  ('1', ['1', '2', '-2']),
  ('1', ['1', '3', '-3']),
  ('1', ['1', '4', '-4']),
  ('1', ['1', '5', '-5']),
  ('1', ['1', '6', '-6']),
  ('2', ['2', '7', '-7']),
  ('2', ['2', '8', '-8']),
  ('2', ['2', '9', '-9'])
```

and I store it in an RDD with two partitions. One partition contains data for *key = '1'* and the other contains data for *key = '2'*. Now, when I run:

```
def do_something(partition):
    print('hello')
    for element in partition:
        if element[0] != '1':
            yield element

my_rdd_new = my_rdd.mapPartitions(do_something)
```

It doesn't print **'hello'** but  my_rdd_new contains the right subset of data, i.e.:

```
  ('2', ['2', '7', '-7']),
  ('2', ['2', '8', '-8']),
  ('2', ['2', '9', '-9'])
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?!

If it helps, I'm using spark 2.0.1 and running the code in Jupyter IPython notebook.

**Update:** It seems *Jupyter IPython* is the problem. I ran it in the command prompt and it works. Now, the question is: Why does it happen and how it can be fixed?!

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the code, in client or cluster mode ?

Comment: @Suresh: I run it on my pc. There is no cluster

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add my comment here. It works if I don't run it from Jupiter notebook! Don't know how this can be explained though!